# AppEngine/Go app won't compile. What did I miss?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am trying to test an AppEngine/Go application. I start `dev_appserver.py` and it begins serving the application, but when I go to `localhost:8080` in my browser, I get:

```
Compile error:
/home/adam/foobar/server/app/server.go:5: can't find import: appengine/users

2011/08/23 19:45:34 go-app-builder: Failed building app: failed running 8g: exit status 1
```

I feel as though I need to do something to make the AppEngine-specific libraries available where GO expects them to be, but I don't really want to run `goinstall` on everything that comes in the AppEngine/Go SDK zip, do I? I seem to have missed an installation step, but for the life of me, I can't figure the sane and right thing to do.

I am on Ubuntu, if that matters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Users API isn't `appengine/users` - it's `appengine/user`. From the example on the [App Engine page](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/go/users/overview.html):

```
import (
    "appengine"
    "appengine/user"
)

func welcome(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
    u := user.Current(c)
    if u == nil {
        url := u.LoginURL(c, "/")
        fmt.Fprintf(w, `<a href="%s">Sign in or register</a>`, url)
        return
    }
    url := user.LogoutURL(c, "/")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, `Welcome, %s! (<a href="%s">sign out</a>)`, u, url)
}
```

Comment: Absolutely correct. I am suitably embarrassed to have posted a typo-based question on StackOverflow. <sigh/>

Comment: No problem at all - an extra set of eyes on a piece of code never hurts :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to compile the code yourself - just run the `dev_appserver` and it will compile it for you whenever the code changes. Have you gone through the [getting started docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/go/gettingstarted/helloworld.html)?

Comment: Nick, the error message that I am seeing is what shows up in the browser after I run `dev_appserver` and navigate to localhost:8080. Yes, I have gone through the getting started docs, but they don't seem to say anything in particular about *installing* the SDK. I unzipped the archive and installed Go and set up my environment variables as best as I could figure out how. Is there something else that I need to do?

Comment: @Adam Oh, you didn't say anything about the message being in your browser. I assumed you were trying to compile it on the command line. I'm not sure, in that case, but I'll go pester the Go guys about it.

Comment: I added the missing details. Thanks for the pestering. It's a bit frustrating to have such basic problems with the Go runtime when I am so comfortable in Python, but Go is pretty sexy.

Comment: The message being in the browser is normal - you should see it on standard error as well in whatever terminal is running `dev_appserver`.